# Multiplication of conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I was looking up on Bayesian networks and came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBQkZdPHlCs). In which it states:
[image]

And I was wondering, how did he get $P(B|A)*P(C|B) = P(B,C|A)$?

Comment: Normally you define
$$
\mathbb{P}[B|A] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[A]}.
$$

Comment: @gt6989b I tried substituting it in but I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I was wondering, how did he get $P(B|A)\cdot P(C|B)=P(B,C|A)$?

By reading the partial diagram $\require{enclose}{\to}\enclose{box}{\enclose{circle}{A\,}\to\enclose{circle}{B\,}\to\enclose{circle}{C\,}}{\to}$ which would factorise as $\mathsf P(A,B,C)=\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B\mid A)\cdot\mathsf P(C\mid B)$ .

Comment: Thank you for your help! But shouldn't $P(A,B,C) = P(A) * P(B|A) * P(C|B,A)$?

Comment: @tangolin No, because $A$ is not a direct parent of $C$ in the given factorisation graph.  This section of the graph encodes that $A$ and $C$ are (conditionally) independent when given $B$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Is there any way to mathematically show the equivalence though? Since I tried and couldn't get it

Comment: @tangolin ...  Divide both sides of the equality by $\mathsf P(A)$ and use the definition of conditional probability on the LHS.  (It cancels on the RHS.)  ...